# Riddle: "Bone of stone, / Marrow of wood..."

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A sunshiny riddle:

> Bone of stone,
> Marrow of wood.
> Stands alone,
> Never understood.
> Forever atone,
> Under the hood.
> Crime condone,
> On sin brood.

What/who is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go with:

> the Christ the Redeemer statue in Rio de Janeiro [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Christ_the_Redeemer_-Cristo_Redentor.jpg/220px-Christ_the_Redeemer-_Cristo_Redentor.jpg]

Bone of stone, marrow of wood.

> It's built of soapstone and concrete.  Concrete would have required wood formwork.

Stands alone, never understood.

> It certainly stands alone on its mountain, and you can stand next to it but not actually under it.

Forever atone, under the hood.

> Atonement is a religious reference.  The hair on the statue looks like a hood at first glance.

Crime condone, on sin brood.

> Crime rates in Rio are very high, and the open arms pose looks like it's welcoming the criminal activity, but it's just a statue so all it can do is brood over it.

And it’s a sunshiny riddle because:

> Sunshine is an album by the band RIO

Comment: @will For some days there I thought I'd stumped everybody... *sigh*